# Finding cheapest way to buy items in different shops, but shops have one time fee

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computer-science-theory

So I have following problem:

There is `k` stores and `n` items. Every store can have these items at different prices (and there are stores that don't have all items). But if you want to buy in a specific store, you must pay one-time fee, which is different for every store. How to find the cheapest way to buy all items?

The only solution I have now is to try every possible combination of shops and look for the cheapest. Is there a better way or some heuristic approximation?

Comment: did you mean every score have an entrance fee?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you want to buy anything in specific store you must pay a fee, no matter how many items you buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pretty simple reduction of 3-SAT to this problem, so it's NP-hard (introduce a store for each variable and for the complement of each variable, one time fee of 1, then have as the items for a store all clauses satisfied by the variable or complement, as well as a special item for each variable which is sold only in the variable and complement store, all of cost 0, and see if you can buy everything for price `k`). So there's not going to be a "better way" in the sense of an algorithm which is guaranteed to produce an optimal result with better complexity than a brute-force search.

I think simulated annealing would work well here: In each annealing step either add or remove a store, then find the lowest cost for that store selection.

Comment: What do you think about using genetic algorithm? I have seen it used in travelling salesman problem.

Comment: @piotros In my opinion, genetic algorithms are one of the least powerful randomized optimization techniques.

Answer (score 2):

You can model this as an [integer linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Constants:
Let `P[i][j]` be the price of item `i` at store `j`, let `F[j]` be the fee for entering store j, and let `W[i]` be the number of item `i` you need to buy. Let `K` be a large constant (larger than `max_{i}(W[i])`).

Variables:
`N[i][j]` will be the number of item `i` you buy from store `j`. `C[j]` will be 1 if you purchased anything from store `j`, otherwise 0.

Then you want to minimize: `sum_{i,j}(P[i][j]*N[i][j]) + sum_{j}(F[j]*C[j])`. That is, you want to minimize the product of the prices with the quantities purchased, plus the shop fees for shops you entered.

Subject to: for all `i`, `sum_{j}(N[i][j]) = W[i]`, and for all `i` and `j`, `C[j]*K >= N[i][j]`. That is, the sum of the quantities of items purchased is what you originally wanted, and the `C[j]*K >= N[i][j]` condition forces `C[j]` to be non-zero if `N[i][j]` is non-zero for some `i`.

All variables must be positive and integral.

Note that both the objective function (that is, the thing you're trying to minimize), and each of the conditions in the "subject to" paragraph are linear in the variables of the problem.

This immediately gives you a way to solve the problem: plug it into an ILP solver, for example [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/). There's a body of theoretical results about approximations and heuristics for solving these problems which you can apply. For example, you can try solving it as a linear program (that is, relaxing the problem so that quantities can be real-valued rather than integral), and then picking the nearest feasible integer-valued solution.